# Refresh Contents Pane in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro

It seems I am missing simple functionality in Pro. How to update Contents pane in ArcGIS Pro other than to remove a layer from it and add it again?

I am working on some script which adds a subtype for a specific layer and it works fine, however, Contents pane is not automatically updated and subtype is not visible in it. There is a workaround where the script will remove a layer from the map(which might remove styling) and add it again.

But is there a simple refresh button for Contents pane or something similar I am missing here?

Comment: Assuming that your script is in ArcPy can you provide some code to illustrate where you are stuck, please?

Comment: Thank you for comment PolyGeo. Sorry if I confused you with an unnecessary example but I was just curious is there something like a refresh button for Contents pane?

Comment: Have you ever seen a subtype in the Contents pane? If so, can you include a picture of it in your question body, please?